# How can i handle a file ByteArray in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a flash recorder which record user input and give me a file Byte-Array in Java-script

now i want to upload that byte-array to the server (MVC3), i wonder how can i do this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send the byte array as raw data to the server using an AJAX request. We could implement a custom model binder which will read the raw request body and map it to a `byte[]`:

```
public class ByteArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var buffer = new byte[request.InputStream.Length];
        request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

then we could have a controller action that will receive this request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload([ModelBinder(typeof(ByteArrayModelBinder))] byte[] buffer)
{
    // TODO: do something with the uploaded data
    return Json(true);
}
```

and finally on the client send the AJAX request:

```
// create sample data from the A,B,C bytes:
var data = String.fromCharCode(65, 66, 67);

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("upload")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: That didnt work with me , first you provided Data Twice so i deleted the first one , now everytime it post to the server it posts the buffer as null!

Comment: @Stacker, oops, my mistake. Well, assuming you have a byte array as shown in my example, you should be able to post it to a controller action that will take a `byte[]` as parameter. Then in the custom model binder that I showed you could read the body of the request stream. I have tested it and it worked fine. Maybe the data you have in your script is not on the same form as I showed? Notice that the `fromCharCode` method doesn't take an array. It takes multiple arguments. So if you have an array `[65, 66, 67]`, it won't work...

Comment: ... in this case you will have to call the `fromCharCode` for each element of your byte array and concatenate it into the final data that you will send to the server.

Comment: i didnt change your code at all i use String.fromCharCode(65, 66, 67);
just as you provided, the funny thing is i put a breakpoint inside BindModel and it never hit it !

Comment: @Stacker, did you put `[ModelBinder(typeof(ByteArrayModelBinder))]` in front of the `byte[]` action argument as shown in my answer? I assume you haven't, which would explain why the custom model binder is not called.

Comment: turned out something really funny ! ByteArrayModelBinder already exist in System.Web.MVC in framework 4.5 so i had to rename your custom class to use it instead of the built in one !, it works great now!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply posting your byte array to a controller method? If your using jquery it would just be a case of using $.ajax or $.post and sending the request to the correct location according to how you have your routing arranged.

Comment: how do i do that ?can you provide me of a sample code please ? as im not sure how im gonna pot a "ByteArray" to a controller

Comment: The method of posting i was reffering to would be the same as in the comments above, something along the ines of:

Comment: '// create sample data from the A,B,C bytes: 
var data = String.fromCharCode(65, 66, 67); 
 
$.ajax({ 
    url: '@Url.Action("upload")', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream', 
    processData: false, 
    data: data, 
    success: function (result) { 
        alert(result); 
    } 
});'